# AWS ALB: unable to get request hostname

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a simple node app listening on `0.0.0.0` sitting behind an application load balancer. Now I need to get hostname of incoming request but it always says `localhost`.
A simple task that seems impossible: ALB does not forward neither the `Host` header, nor the `X-Forwarded-Host` header.

Or am I missing something? How do I get request hostname?

Comment: I think you could only get it using NLB.

Comment: Interesting, I'm also rather surprised because it's such a basic thing!

Comment: are you running a proxy in front of the node app?  i.e. apache or nginx?

Comment: @chris, no, the app runs in a container sitting behind the balancer.

Answer (score 1):

An ALB sends the `X-Fowarded-For` header, with the IP the request originated from. The headers an ALB sends are documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/x-forwarded-headers.html).

Comment: Thanks, Mark. I've seen that page, but like I mentioned there's no `X-Forwarded-Host` header available which would solve the problem we're having.

Comment: The `Host` header would be there if the request came from a web browser. The ALB will forward along any headers that are in the initial request. The `x-forwarded-*` headers are headers specifically added to the request by the load balancer.  If the `Host` header is not there, then it means the request came from a type of HTTP client that does not set the `Host` header.